# How do you get a tricky function reference?

Tags: erlang

How do you get a reference to a function in a module when the module is dynamically specified and you'll be passing it to a higher order function?

Ex:

```
Mod = compare_funs,
lists:sort(fun Mod:compare/2, List).
```

Only, this won't compile. One way would be to wrap a call to the target function in an anonymous fun, but I was wondering if there's a way to get a reference directly.

Comment: For the record, [EEP-23](http://www.erlang.org/eeps/eep-0023.html) is a proposal to make this possible.  There is [an implementation](https://github.com/bjorng/otp/commits/bg%2Fexternal-funs), but it was [dropped](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.erlang.patches/1198) from the pu tree a while ago.

Comment: @Travis Webb - Sure, erlang is a dynamic language, it makes this kind of thing possible. For example, you can call a function in a dynamically specified module with Mod:hello(). Notice the capital: Mod is a variable. You can do that. In this case, as I mentioned above, the problem is solvable by wrapping a dynamic call in an anonymous fun and passing that to 'sort', already. Just wanted a cleaner way. The purpose in this case is that several different modules know the way this list should be sorted, and which module is responsible isn't known until runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation at:

http://www.erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/funs.html#id59209

> We can also refer to a function
>   defined in a different module with the
>   following syntax:
>
> ```
> F = {Module, FunctionName}
> ```
>
> In this case, the function must be
>   exported from the module in question.

For example, you might do:

```
-module(test).

-export([compare/2, test/2]).

compare(X, Y) when X > Y ->
    true;
compare(X, Y) ->
    false.

test(Mod, List) ->
    lists:sort({Mod, compare}, List).


1> test:test(test, [1,3,2]).
[3,2,1]
```

Comment: DON'T use this! This "feature" is seriously deprecated (it was invented before funs were added to Erlang), and might be removed completely one day. I think HiPE refuses to handle it at all. As you said, you can use a wrapper like fun (...) -> M:F(...) end, until EEP 23 gets implemented.

Comment: Didn't know about EEP-23. +1 for that approach. It's probably worth adding a note to that example in the official documentation.